# How to append an image to a video using OpenCV or FFMPEG or Moviepy or other libraries?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, moviepy

Do you know a library in Python to add a frame image to an existing video? The result video must have the same quality as the image.

I tried to use OpenCV to add google image: https://www.google.com/search?q=google&sxsrf=ALiCzsZhrdoHnOTmg0We4dxtguCqzma5Jg:1657603343101&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTh8bTzfL4AhWhplYBHfXNAKwQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1492&bih=739&dpr=1.25#imgrc=PRtenhDnrVrfOM

But the quality decreases when the video elongates.

Here is the final result video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArDvoX-kN9H_oLbACk3kU1Cid93SMczC/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code using OpenCV:

```
        image = cv2.imread(path_image)
        height, width, dimensions = image.shape
            
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(path_video)
        
        
        frames = []
        while(True):
            
            ret, frame = video.read()
            
            if ret == True: 
                frames.append(frame)
                # frame = frame.resize(frame, (width, height), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                
                # Press S on keyboard 
                # to stop the process
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
                    break
            # Break the loop
            else:
                break
            
        video2 = cv2.VideoWriter(path_video,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 30, (width, height))
        for frame in frames:
            video2.write(frame)
        video2.write(image)
        video2.release()  # releasing the video generated     
        print("Added {}".format(image_name))
```

I hope to improve the quality of this video.

Comment: Is your input video mjpeg and your image jpeg?

Comment: Can you please post the input video and the input image? There is no generic solution... The solution depends on the video codec, video container and encoding parameters. It is not promised that the quality of the image stays as is.

Comment: What if you moved line 13 to line 27? frames.append(frame)

Comment: The input image is the image above after I downloaded it to my computer. The input video just has one frame, which is that image.

Comment: Adter I run that script n times (It will append n frames to the video input).

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple way to achieve that using moviepy would be the following:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

maxsize = (target_width, target_height)
jpg_image = Image.open(path_to_the_image)
# modify the image's resolution to be the target one
jpg_image.thumbnail(maxsize, Image.ANTIALIAS)
jpg_image = np.array(jpg_image)
image = ImageClip(jpg_image).set_duration(target_duration)

clip = VideoFileClip(path_to_the_video)
video = concatenate([image, clip], method="compose")
video.write_videofile("output_example.mp4", fps=target_fps)
```

As long as you set the target resolution of the image to match the video's one you are set with just that.

Comment: Does it re encoding the video?

Comment: It does re-encode the video. You can check this thread for more info on it:
https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/737

If my reply is answering your question please accept it as the answer.